How to make paddingHorizontal or margineHorizantal set to auto in reactNative
I am new to React Native, and things have changed here. I couldn't get React Native to set auto padding for the X axis, which was not a big deal in Bootstrap and CSS.
Did react-native eliminate the auto value or is there any trick to it?
I tried, giving the auto as value with and without quotation but no luck.
is there any trick to it? or React Native completly eleminated it?

The value auto is not a valid value for the padding property but the auto value can be applied to margin.
